# Erro ao obter conteudo de site externo

Tags: php

Tenho um codigo que busca um conteudo dentro de um site externo no caso G1, ele funciona perfeitamente mas me traz com o CSS da pagina sendo assim nao posso personalizar para deixar no padrão de meu site, pesquisando achei outro que me mostra os dados sem formatação me dando liberdade para manipulado da melhor maneira possivel, mas quando solicito um conteudo extenso ele nao abre me dando o seguinte erro.

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ruralrio\blog\2.php on line 15
```

meu codigo e esse

```
<?php

$url_base = "http://g1.globo.com/economia/noticia/2015/07/justica-paulista-suspende-multa-de-r-3-milhoes-ao-mcdonalds.html";
$texto = preg_replace("/((\r\n|\t)+|\s{2,})/", "",
file_get_contents($url_base));

preg_match('/<title>(.*)<\/title>/i', stripslashes($texto), $titulo);
preg_match('/<h1 class="entry-title">(.*)<\/h1>/i', stripslashes($texto), $titulomateria);
preg_match('/<h2>(.*)<\/h2>/i', stripslashes($texto), $titulomateria2);
preg_match('/<div class="materia-conteudo entry-content" id="materia-letra">(.*)<\/div>/i', stripslashes($texto), $titulomateria3);

echo strip_tags($titulo[1]) . "<br /><br />";
echo strip_tags($titulomateria[1]) . "<br /><br />";
echo strip_tags($titulomateria2[1]) . "<br /><br />";
echo strip_tags($titulomateria3[2]) . "<br /><br />";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possíveis problemas:

1. `file_get_contents` não está habilitado para acessar urls externas, para fixar use:

   Edite o php.ini e troque `allow_url_fopen=0` por `allow_url_fopen=1` (http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php)
2. `file_get_contents` requer contexto com user-agent, é necessário então fazer algo como:

   ```
   $headers = array(
       'Accept-language: pt-br',
       'User-Agent: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
   );

   $opts = array(
       'http'=>array(
           'method' => 'GET',
           'header' => implode(PHP_EOL, $headers)
       )
   );

   $context = stream_context_create($opts);

   $texto = file_get_contents('http://g1.globo.com/economia/noticia/2015/07/justica-paulista-suspende-multa-de-r-3-milhoes-ao-mcdonalds.html', false, $context);
   ```
3. Ao invés de usar `preg_match` tente usar DOM, por exemplo:

   ```
   $doc = new DOMDocument();

   //Modifica o estado
   $libxml_previous_state = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

   //Faz um parse na string
   $doc->loadHTML($texto);

   //Limpa os erros
   libxml_clear_errors();

   //Restaura ao normal
   libxml_use_internal_errors($libxml_previous_state);
   ```

   <sub>Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17559716/1518921</sub>

   E depois use métodos como [getelementsbytagname](http://php.net/manual/fr/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php), [getelementbyid](http://php.net/manual/fr/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) e [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domxpath.php) (para facilitar)

O código final deve ficar algo como:

```
<?php
$headers = array(
    'Accept-language: pt-br',
    'User-Agent: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
);

$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => implode(PHP_EOL, $headers)
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$texto = file_get_contents('http://g1.globo.com/economia/noticia/2015/07/justica-paulista-suspende-multa-de-r-3-milhoes-ao-mcdonalds.html', false, $context);

$doc = new DOMDocument();

// modify state
$libxml_previous_state = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// parse
$doc->loadHTML($texto);

// handle errors
libxml_clear_errors();

// restore
libxml_use_internal_errors($libxml_previous_state);

$tmp = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

foreach ($tmp as $value) {
    echo 'Titulo:', $value->nodeValue, '<br>';
}

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$tmp = $xpath->query('//h1[contains(@class,"entry")]');

foreach ($tmp as $value) {
    echo 'h1.entry:', $value->nodeValue, '<br>';
}

$tmp = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h2');

foreach ($tmp as $value) {
    echo 'h2:', $value->nodeValue, '<br>';
}

$tmp = $doc->getElementById('materia-letra')->getElementsByTagName('div');

foreach ($tmp as $value) {
    echo '#materia-letra:', $value->nodeValue, '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Boa tarde @guilhermenascimento testei aqui desta maneira que me passou mas gerou outro erro e nao abre o restante da pagina



`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''User-Agent: '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ruralrio\blog\2.php on line 6`

Comment: Continuo com o mesmo erro :(, o que pode ser em, pois texto pequeno ele pega normalmente mas o texto grande ja nao. ja o outro codigo que nao tem como eu personalizar exibe tudo sem falhas e corretamente mas esse que quero separar os conteudos ja gera esses erros

Comment: não sei o que ta havendo aqui no meu mais sempre o mesmo erro. kkk ele me retorna assim `Economia - Justiça paulista suspende multa de R$ 3 milhões ao McDonald's

Justiça paulista suspende multa de R$ 3 milhões ao McDonald's

Recurso do Procon-SP foi recusado pelo Tribunal de Justiça de São Paulo.Entidade alega que rede veiculou comerciais abusivos do McLanche Feliz.


Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ruralrio\blog\2.php on line 27`

Comment: Cara to usando apenas esse codigo sem mais nada na pagina. no servidor na web ele nao gera o erro e nao exibe o 4º item ja no local ele mostra que tem esse erro

Comment: a pagina apenas com o textos

[http://ruralrio.com.br/blog/2.php]

e a pagina com todas as tag e css

[http://ruralrio.com.br/blog/index.g1economia2.php?url=http://g1.globo.com/economia/noticia/2015/07/justica-paulista-suspende-multa-de-r-3-milhoes-ao-mcdonalds.html]

Comment: continuei com o preg_match pois ao colocar o DOM gerou mais erros pois nao sei usar corretamente o DOM

Comment: `preg_match` é bem mais complexo e não é muito recomendável para isto (ao menos a maioria das pessoas concorda). Qual erro gerou no DOM?

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag header invalid in Entity, line: 151 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ruralrio\blog\2.php on line 19

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID frmBuscaScroll already defined in Entity, line: 237 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ruralrio\blog\2.php on line 19

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID menu-2-noticias already defined in Entity, line: 677 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ruralrio\blog\2.php on line 19

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 4552 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ruralrio\blog\2.php on line 19

Comment: Agora limpou os erros mais nao constroi a pagina fica em branco

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25506/discussion-between-cristiano-cardoso-silva-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Comment: Justamente o que eu precisava Muito Obrigado irei estudar aqui como funciona..

Comment: @CristianoCardosoSilva estude sim :) DOM é o que há kkk