# Pegar os últimos IDS

Tags: php

Quero pegar os últimos ID's [deste site](http://hebbohotel.com.br/swf/gordon/RELEASE-HEBBO/effectmap.xml)

Não quero pegar os IDS com número mais altos e sim os últimos da ordem:
Exemplo:

```
<effect id="195" lib="CrossTrainer" type="fx" revision="62175"/>
<effect id="500" lib="BigSpn" type="fx" revision="90000"/>
<effect id="501" lib="SmallS" type="fx" revision="90000"/>
<effect id="502" lib="BigJmp" type="fx" revision="90000"/>
<effect id="503" lib="SmallJ" type="fx" revision="90000"/>
<effect id="504" lib="Hoverplan1" type="fx" revision="90000"/>
<effect id="505" lib="Hoverplan2" type="fx" revision="90000"/>
<effect id="506" lib="Hoverplan3" type="fx" revision="90000"/>
<effect id="507" lib="TrampolineTest" type="fx" revision="90000"/>
```

Pegar somente os 3 últimos IDs... "505,506,507"

Comment: Poderia usar o `str_split()` para cortar a string em `id="` dai apos cortar você em um `foreach` pega apenas as três primeiras letras de cada item.

Comment: Como ficaria o código inteiro?

Comment: Esse codigo dai é realmente uma string? Vou postar a resposta.

Comment: não entendi sua pergunta, este código que mostrei é apenas um exemplo dos IDS que é para pegar do link: http://hebbohotel.com.br/swf/gordon/RELEASE-HEBBO/effectmap.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sendo um XML pode usar o [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
$url = 'http://hebbohotel.com.br/swf/gordon/RELEASE-HEBBO/effectmap.xml';

$xml = file_get_contents($url);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$effects = $dom->getElementsByTagName('effect');

foreach ($effects as $effect) {
    echo $effect->getAttribute('id'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

O exemplo anterior servia somente para entender, para obter os 3 últimos ids use array (converta com `iterator_to_array`) e use a função `array_slice` assim:

```
$url = 'http://hebbohotel.com.br/swf/gordon/RELEASE-HEBBO/effectmap.xml';

$xml = file_get_contents($url);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$effects = iterator_to_array($dom->getElementsByTagName('effect'));//Passa para array

//-3 no segundo parametro pega os 3 ultimos itens
$effects = array_slice($effects, -3);

foreach ($effects as $effect) {
    echo $effect->getAttribute('id'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Note que `file_get_contents` falhar você pode ser devido a não habilitado o acesso a urls externas, você pode habilitar isso no php.ini (como expliquei nesta resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/72746/3635):

```
allow_url_fopen=1
```

Ou pode trocar `file_get_contents` por curl, assim:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://hebbohotel.com.br/swf/gordon/RELEASE-HEBBO/effectmap.xml';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); //Transferência binaria
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Força retornar transferência na variável

$xml = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$effects = iterator_to_array($dom->getElementsByTagName('effect'));//Passa para array
```

### Respostas compactadas GZ

As vezes pode ocorrer de mesmo você não solicitando o header `Accept-Encoding` o servidor ainda enviar, isso é um problema talvez de má configuração, no caso o link que deseja acessar esta com este problema, tentei enviar os headers, mas aparentemente não funciona, então uma solução é usar o `gzdecode` do php, assim:

- `file_get_contents`

  ```
  $url = 'http://hebbohotel.com.br/swf/gordon/RELEASE-HEBBO/effectmap.xml';

  $xml = gzdecode(file_get_contents($url));

  $dom = new DOMDocument;
  $dom->loadXML($xml);
  $effects = iterator_to_array($dom->getElementsByTagName('effect'));//Passa para array
  ```
- `curl`

  ```
  $url = 'http://hebbohotel.com.br/swf/gordon/RELEASE-HEBBO/effectmap.xml';

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); //Transferência binaria
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Força retornar transferência na variável

  $xml = gzdecode(curl_exec($ch));

  curl_close($ch);

  $dom = new DOMDocument;
  $dom->loadXML($xml);
  $effects = iterator_to_array($dom->getElementsByTagName('effect'));//Passa para array
  ```

Comment: @Rafa editei a resposta, leia o final que adicione e tente, se houver qualquer problema adicione no começo `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` apenas pra depurar, depois que estiver funcionando pode remover o `error_reporting` e o `ini_set`, leia mais sobre isto em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/3635

Comment: @Rafa voce não pode esperar m codigo pronto aqui no site pois não sabemos o que você quer fazer, o restante do seu código, o site não é pra pegar codigo pronto e sim tratar duvidas específicas, como a sua que já foi tratada nas duas resposta, agora se sua aplicação do codigo no seu contexto está sendo errada aí ja fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento olhe oque deu http://rafagarcia.eu5.org/efeito.php

Comment: Você acha que em javascript não seria melhor?

Comment: @Rafa Eram pequenos problemas no código, provavelmente você usou o curl, eu corrigi troquei `array_values` por `iterator_to_array` e no curl eu adicione o `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` que estava faltando. Teste agora os exemplos.

Comment: Continua com errinhos! e está tudo com letras como se fosse criptografado http://rafagarcia.eu5.org/efeito.php se puder contatar pelo skype ia me ajudar mais! skype: rafa.garcia.gamer

Comment: Usei o da última edição da postagem

Comment: o curl, porque o file_get_contents fica tudo branco a página!

Comment: @Rafa faz o seguinte, cria um novo arquivo php chamado teste.php e depois cola esse conteudo nele e salva: http://pastebin.com/raw/q5kMkxRv então acesse ele

Comment: Deu certo obrigado mano! <3

Comment: @Rafa recomendo que estude as funções e estude php, entenda como um comentário pra você se tornar melhor, muitos dos erros foram por você desconhecer as funções que tentou usar e não entender as explicações que passei, foi apenas no copy+paste e por isso falhou, é só uma critica construtiva :)

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se vai ajudar pois vocês está trabalhando com `XML`, logo, não postou se está trabalhando com ele como `string` ou transformando-o em `array`.

Na realidade não usei o `str_slipt`, fiz de outra forma.

Fiz uma classe para dar conta do recado, **GetIds.php**:

```
<?php
class GetIds
{
    /*
    *   Atributos
    */
    private $string = null;
    private $limit = null;
    private $split = null;

    /*
    *   Construtor com insercao de um atributo
    */
    public function __construct($string = null)
    {
        $this->string = $string;
    }

    /*
    *   Varre atributo string até que o caracter lido não seja string, apos iss une os numeros formando o id
    *   @return result - array com os ids
    */
    public function getIds()
    {
        $this->appLimit();

        $result = array();
        foreach($this->split as $value)
        {
            $isNumber = 0;
            for($letter = 0; $letter < strlen($value); $letter ++)
            {

                if(filter_var($value[$letter], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) or $value[$letter] === '0')
                    $isNumber ++;
                else
                    break;

            }
            for($letter = 0; $letter < count($value); $letter ++)
            {
                array_push($result, mb_substr($value, 0, $isNumber));
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /*
    *   Muda o valor do atributo limit
    */
    public function setLimit($newLimit)
    {
        $this->limit = $newLimit;
    }

    /*
    *   Separa o atributo string em determinado separador passado por parametro
    */
    public function setSplit($separator)
    {
        if(!is_null($this->string))
            $this->split = explode('id="', $this->string);
        unset($this->split[0]);
    }

    /*
    *   Apaga elementos do array deixando os x ultimos
    */
    private function appLimit()
    {
        if(!is_null($this->string) and !is_null($this->limit))
        {
            $crop = count($this->split) - $this->limit;
            for($item = 0; $item < $crop; $item ++)
            {
                unset($this->split[$item]);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Arquivo **teste.php**:

```
<?php
require_once 'GetIds.php';
$myResult =
'<effect id="195" lib="CrossTrainer" type="fx" revision="62175"/>
<effect id="500" lib="BigSpn" type="fx" revision="90000"/>
<effect id="501" lib="SmallS" type="fx" revision="90000"/>
<effect id="502" lib="BigJmp" type="fx" revision="90000"/>
<effect id="503" lib="SmallJ" type="fx" revision="90000"/>
<effect id="5" lib="Hoverplan1" type="fx" revision="90000"/>
<effect id="122150" lib="Hoverplan2" type="fx" revision="90000"/>
<effect id="50654" lib="Hoverplan3" type="fx" revision="90000"/>
<effect id="502170" lib="TrampolineTest" type="fx" revision="90000"/>';

// cria uma classe com a string de resultado
$ids = new GetIds($myResult);

// define o limite para 3
$ids->setLimit(3);

// define onde devo cortar o resultado
$ids->setSplit('id="');

// pega os ids encontrados 
$result = $ids->getIds();

var_dump($result);
```

**Saída:**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '122150' (length=6)
  1 => string '50654' (length=5)
  2 => string '502170' (length=6)
```

**Obs:** Alterei os ids apenas para mostrar que funciona com id de comprimentos diferentes.

Comment: O `var_dump` exibe o array de uma forma mais elegante, os ids estão armazenado no aray, se nao entendeu isso sugiro que estude array e mais sobre linguagem de programação